# Unable to install Mongodb on Ubuntu 14.04. (error "status: Unknown job: mongod")

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu

I'm trying to install Mongodb for Ubuntu 14.04. I followed the official documentation on Mongodb installation from here - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

I ran the following commands:-

1. sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv
   2930ADAE8CAF5059EE73BB4B58712A2291FA4AD5
2. echo "deb [ arch=amd64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu
   trusty/mongodb-org/3.6 multiverse" | sudo tee
   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.6.list
3. sudo apt-get update
4. sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org

When I execute the command #4, I get this near the end of the output:

```
Setting up mongodb-org-server (3.6.3) ...
runlevel:/var/run/utmp: No such file or directory
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start.
initctl: Unknown job: mongod
Setting up mongodb-org-mongos (3.6.3) ...
Setting up mongodb-org-tools (3.6.3) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Setting up mongodb-org (3.6.3) ...
```

After this when I run `sudo service mongod start` I get:

`start: Unknown job: mongod`

And running `mongo` results in:-

```
MongoDB shell version v3.6.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2018-03-30T12:45:43.635+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2018-03-30T12:45:43.635+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

`mongo --version` results in:-

```
MongoDB shell version v3.6.3
git version: 9586e557d54ef70f9ca4b43c26892cd55257e1a5
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
allocator: tcmalloc
modules: none
build environment:
    distmod: ubuntu1404
    distarch: x86_64
    target_arch: x86_64
```

Both `/var/log/mongodb` and `/var/lib/mongodb` are empty folders.

I've uninstalled this using instructions on the same docs page linked above, and reinstalled it. No change.

Can't believe official instructions fail and I can't find solution for this anywhere.